# Can you make a non-monk weapon into a monk weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, monk

Are there any feats, archetypes or similar in Pathfinder that allow you to treat a non-monk weapon as a monk weapon?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What weapon are you interested in, and what particular feature that depends on a monk weapon (typically only Flurry of Blows) do you wish to allow? For example, a Zen Archer archetype can use long and short bows (including composite) to make a flurry of blows, even though the weapons are not otherwise treated as monk weapons. If features that allow using a weapon in flurry of blows attacks is sufficient, please update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Can you port 3.5e material? That definitely had a feat that was a simple “pick a weapon you’re proficient with; that now works with monk class features.” Vastly superior to the garbage options apparently offered by Pathfinder.

Comment: Yeah for an accurate answer, we'll probably need more details. I can think of 3 specific cases where you can count a weapon as a Monk weapon, but without knowing the reason, that will quickly turn into a list answer if we have to go and find every instance of that allowance. Furthermore, the only reasons I can think of why you would want to do this are proficiency and the Flurry class feature. If it's one of those or something else entirely, that could change answers significantly.

Comment: Yeah we could benefit from telling us the purpose of the question. Crusader's Flurry is  a fine (though weak) option to get *any* weapon to count as monk weapon, but there may be a much better option that isn't gated behind heavy requirements.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, you can

[Crusader's Flurry](http://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Crusader%27s%20Flurry) (from Ultimate Combat) is a feat commonly taken for that purpose, it will allow your character to take a weapon, related to your chosen deity, and treat that weapon as a *monk weapon* for all purposes.

> You learned to use your deity’s favored weapon as part of your martial arts form.
>
> **Prerequisites**: Channel energy class feature, flurry of blows class feature, Weapon Focus with your deity’s favored melee weapon.
>
> **Benefit**: You can use your deity’s favored weapon as if it were a monk weapon.

Do note, however, that it has heavy requirements to base your build around. It requires both channel energy and flurry of blows. While this could be obtained by multiclassing, you are probably combining two medium BAB classes, which will hurt you heavily and not really justify the combination just to take the feat.

The [Sacred Fist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest/archetypes/paizo-warpriest-archetypes/sacred-fist/) [warpriest](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest/) archetype will grant you both requirements, but you still gotta waste a feat on [Weapon Focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest/#TOC-Focus-Weapon), and probably another on the weapon proficiency, as the archetype loses both Weapon Focus and proficiency on all simple and martial weapons, substituting their proficiencies to a list similar to the monk's (which is pretty bad). The weapon proficiency has better ways to obtain, such as using a trait or multiclassing into a full BAB class, which is probably a bad idea as it will slow your spellcasting progression.

Comment: The [Sacred Fist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest/archetypes/paizo-warpriest-archetypes/sacred-fist/) archetype of the [Warpriest](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest/) hybrid class gets both Flurry of Blows and Channel Energy (though the latter only by 4th - a cleric/monk multiclass is probably more efficient).

Comment: Thanks, Carcer, I will update. I had looked at both the sacred fist and champion of irori when I first wrote it, because I was certain that *someone* had both without multiclass, and while the paladin archetype never gets flurry, I forgot that warpriests could channel using their fervor points (which is usually a bad idea).

Comment: Why on *earth* did they feel the need to gate that so hard? This isn’t worth a feat to begin with, to say nothing of two feats and inefficient multiclassing.